# Remove the Custom Post Type name from the URL

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

Below is the example of what I would like to obtain:

**Scenario:**

CPT -> Structures

TAXONOMY(related) -> Type [Hotels, Restaurants, etc...]

**My URL now**

mysite/structures/hotels/hilton/

**what I would like to achieve**

mysite/hotels/hilton

By applying the rewrite to the custom post type, the standard pages and posts of the site return a 404 error. The custom post type and taxonomy archives, however, work correctly and the URL and links are displayed as I would like.

How can I fix for error 404 in standard pages?